# Is this the correct way to backup a file with streams and exceptions?

Tags: java

So I've written a simple backup file method in my java code, but when I test the method in my test class, and check my folder again, I don't see a copy or backup file created, even though I get the success message. Is this is even correct or am I missing something?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BasicFile {

File file1;
JFileChooser selection;
File file2 = new File(".", "Backup File");

public BasicFile() {
    selection = new JFileChooser(".");
}

public void selectFile() {
    int status = selection.showOpenDialog(null);

    try {
        if (status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        file1 = selection.getSelectedFile();

        if (!file1.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found ", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void backupFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    DataInputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file1));
        out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file2));

        try {
            while (true) {
                byte data = in.readByte();
                out.writeByte(data);
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File has been backed up!",
                    "Backup Complete!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found ",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            display(e.toString(), "Error");
        }
    }

}

boolean exists() {
    return file1.exists();
}

public String toString() {
    return file1.getName() + "\n" + file1.getAbsolutePath() + "\n" + file1.length() + " bytes";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, but horribly inefficient. You don't need the `DataInputStream` or `DataOutputStream` either. The canonical way to copy a stream in Java is:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more if you like
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

This code doesn't throw `EOFException` so you need to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: My professor told me that I had to use the DataInputSteam, DataOutputStream, ReadByte, and WriteByte classes I:

Comment: In that case I see nothing wrong with your code. Strange constraints. The'Backup File' should be in the current directory from which you're running this code. But when you get any exception other than `EOFException` here, you should display the exception's own message, not one of your own. For example 'File not found' is not a correct message for the `catch (IOException)` following the catch for `EOFException.`